# Temporary tables in Stored procedure are not accesing data?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

This is My code

```
create proc TEMP
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TEMP1;
    SET @SQL ='SELECT CUSTOMERS,AREA,HOUSEHOLDS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INTO #TEMP1'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'FROM NEW'+CHAR(10)
    PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP2') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TEMP2;
    SET @SQL ='SELECT CUSTOMERS,AREA,VEHICELS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INTO #TEMP2'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'FROM OLD'+CHAR(10)
    PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP3') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TEMP3;
    SET @SQL ='SELECT 0.VEHICELS,C.HOUSEHOLDS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INTO #TEMP3'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'FROM #TEMP1 C'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INNER JOIN #TEMP2 O '+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'on C.CUSTOMERS=O.CUSTOMERS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'AND C.AREA=O.AREA'+CHAR(10)
    PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)
    END
```

My error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#TEMP1'.
```

First TEMP1 and TEMP2 are working well, but when it comes to TEMP3 it doesn't access TEMP1 where the data is present

Can you guys check this confusing problem ???

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE ##T1 (Col1 varchar(20))'
EXEC(@sql)
INSERT INTO ##T1 (Col1) VALUES ('This will work.')
SELECT * FROM ##T1
```

DO WE GET ANY PROBLEMS IN FUTURE IF WE USE GLOBALTEMPORARY TABLES???

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this as dynamic SQL and using `EXEC`. `EXEC` creates a new scope for executing the provided query. When a scope exits, any temp tables created within that scope are dropped.

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL? If you use a normal SQL your temp tables are visibles in all execution of your SP, so you can populate temp3 with temp1 and temp2.

Answer (score 0):

once the exec finishes executing the `#temp` table is deleted
maybe if you try using a wider scope, it could succeed, I don't know.

try something like this.

```
create proc TEMP
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @now datetime;
    DECLARE @TempTableTableSuffix sysname
    SET @now = GETDATE()

    select @TempTableTableSuffix = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(int,RAND(DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@now)+1000*(DATEPART(SECOND,@now)+60*(DATEPART(MINUTE,@now)+60*DATEPART(HOUR,@now)))) * 100000000))

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
    SET @SQL ='SELECT CUSTOMERS,AREA,HOUSEHOLDS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INTO ##TEMP1' + @TempTableTableSuffix + CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'FROM NEW'+CHAR(10)
    PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)
    SET @SQL ='SELECT CUSTOMERS,AREA,VEHICELS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INTO ##TEMP2' + @TempTableTableSuffix + CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'FROM OLD'+CHAR(10)
    PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)
    SET @SQL ='SELECT 0.VEHICELS,C.HOUSEHOLDS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INTO ##TEMP3'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'FROM ##TEMP1' + + @TempTableTableSuffix + '  C'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'INNER JOIN #TEMP2'+ @TempTableTableSuffix  + ' O '+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'on C.CUSTOMERS=O.CUSTOMERS'+CHAR(10)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +'AND C.AREA=O.AREA'+CHAR(10)
    PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

anyway, I think you don't need `dynamic SQL` for this.

Comment: Global varaible also not working..Invalid object name '##TEMP1'.

Answer (score 0):

Use single EXEC -

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP1;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP2;    
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP3') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP3;        


SET @SQL = ' SELECT CUSTOMERS,AREA,HOUSEHOLDS'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INTO #TEMP1'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM NEW'+CHAR(10)

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT CUSTOMERS,AREA,VEHICELS'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INTO #TEMP2'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM OLD'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT 0.VEHICELS,C.HOUSEHOLDS'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INTO #TEMP3'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM #TEMP1 C'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INNER JOIN #TEMP2 O '+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' on C.CUSTOMERS=O.CUSTOMERS'+CHAR(10)
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND C.AREA=O.AREA'+CHAR(10)
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: The right way to show code here on StackOverflow is to indent every line by four spaces (or just highlight the block and hit the `{}` button and the editor will do it for you). `<pre>` blocks sort of work, but don't turn on the syntax highlighting.